# Absolute positioning for label in plot3d

Tags: graphics3d, labeling

I want to place a caption at the bottom of a Plot3D graphic that doesn't move as I rotate the plot with the mouse. I have tried two approaches, neither of which is satisfactory.

My first approach is to position `Graphics3D@Text` under the 3D plot. This method forces in the caption's position to move relative to the 3D plot. Here is my stripped down code for this attempt:

```
Show[
 Plot3D[(y^2 - x^2 - 1/6 x^3), {x, -8, 5}, {y, -6, 6}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 60, PlotPoints -> 50],

 Graphics3D@Text[Style["Caption goes here", 14,
 Black, FontFamily -> "Helv"], {9, -10, -10}]
]
```

My second approach is to use `PlotLabel` in Plot3D. Although the label remains relatively fixed in position, it appears at the top of the 3D plot and I want it to appear at the bottom of the 3D plot. Here is my stripped down code for this attempt:

```
Plot3D[(y^2 - x^2 - 1/6 x^3), {x, -8, 5}, {y, -6, 6}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 60, PlotPoints -> 50,
 PlotLabel -> Style["Caption goes here", 14, FontFamily -> "Helv"]]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: A few duplicates: [(25282)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25282), [(85304)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85304), [(95084)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95084)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

From the comments what I believe you want is the rotating window not to resize as you rotate.  This happens because the default `RotatingAction` is `"Fit"`.  You need it to be `"Clip"`.

```
Labeled[
 Plot3D[(y^2 - x^2 - 1/6 x^3), {x, -8, 5}, {y, -6, 6}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 60, PlotPoints -> 50,
  RotationAction -> "Clip"],
 Style["Caption goes here", 14, FontFamily -> "Helv"],
 Bottom]
```

Now the window is not resized and the label does not jump around.

**Original Post**

You may use `Inset` in the `Epilog` option.

```
Plot3D[(y^2 - x^2 - 1/6 x^3), {x, -8, 5}, {y, -6, 6}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 60, PlotPoints -> 50,
 Epilog -> {Inset[Style["Caption goes here", 14, Black, FontFamily -> "Helv"], 
    {Center, Bottom}, {Center, Bottom}]}
]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your suggestion is helpful but does not do what I want. Let me rephrase my original question. I would like the caption to behave like a FrameLabel in 2D graphics. Can my 3D plot be rotated in some sort of fixed frame and the caption be positioned below such a fixed frame?

Comment: @Stephen Have you seen [`Labeled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html).

Comment: @Stephen Actually, you just need to add the [`RotationAction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotationAction.html) option to your `PlotLabel` code.

Comment: @Stephen See update.

Comment: Excellent! RotationAction fixed the caption. BTW, of what value is RotationControl?

Comment: @Stephen See (these Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=RotationControl); the settings are mention under the option `Method` in the docs for [`Graphics3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html).

Comment: @Stephen I believe the default is `"Globe"`. You can check with `Method /. AbsoluteOptions[g]`. Where `g` is the result of your `Plot3D`, so`g = Plot3D[...]`.